# Want to write csv after concatenating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


os.chdir('E:\in\extracted')

file_list = glob.glob('*.csv')
df_list = []
col_names = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Temp', 'DewTemp', 'Pressure', 'WinDir', 'WindSpeed',
             'Sky', 'Precip1', 'Precip6', 'ID']


def outfile():
    new_path = r'E:\out\Concatenated.csv'
    if not os.path.exists(new_path):
        os.makedirs(new_path)


for file_name in file_list:
    print(file_name)
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)
    df_list.append(df)
concat_df = pd.concat(df_list)
concat_df.columns = col_names
concat_df = pd.DataFrame.to_csv(path_or_buf=outfile()) #Says I need 'Self'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jesse/PycharmProjects/pythonnewtutorial/Concatenate.py", line 27, in 
    concat_df.to_csv(path_or_buf=outfile())
TypeError: to_csv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

When I checked [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv), it said only the path is required.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `to_csv` as a method on the dataframe itself:

```
concat_d.to_csv(outfile()) #Says I need 'Self'
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work when I print(concact_df.head) the data is there, just makes "Concatenated.csv" into a folder for some reason.

Comment: your code should be `if not os.path.exists("E:\out"): os.makedirs("E:\out")`

Comment: then just `concat_d.to_csv("E:\out\outfile.csv")`

Comment: your outfile function doesn't have a `return` so when you give it as an argument, it will be null

Comment: Works great thanks for the explanation too, figured it had to do with the outfile.